# How to install private pods with GitHub Actions?

Tags: xcode, github, cocoapods, github-actions

I'm trying to install my dependencies on my workflow script. However, some are private pods, and it gives me this error when I try and do `bundle exec pod install`:

```
Cloning spec repo `cocoapods` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs`
Cloning spec repo `keterauk` from `https://github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs` named `keterauk`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/runner/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

`pod repo add...` results in this error: `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured` even when i have my personal access token (secret) added.

Here's my full script:

```yaml
name: Swift

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - enhancement/*
      - develop
      - develop/*
      - release
      - release/*

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        destination: ['platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.3,name=iPhone 11']
        xcode: ['/Applications/Xcode_11.6.app/Contents/Developer']
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.STRIVE_ACTIONS_SECRET }} # PAT
      - name: Bundle Update
        run: gem install bundler:1.17.2
      - name: Bundle Install
        run: bundle install

# Currently fails here...
      - name: Specs Repo
        run: pod repo add Strive-Pod-Specs https://github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs.git

      - name: Dependencies
        run: bundle exec pod install
        env:
          DEVELOPER_DIR: ${{ matrix.xcode }}
      - name: Build and test
        run: bundle exec fastlane scan --destination "${destination}" --scheme "CI"
        env:
          destination: ${{ matrix.destination }}
          DEVELOPER_DIR: ${{ matrix.xcode }}
```

How can I install private pods with my workflow GitHub Actions script?

Note: I'm also trying to do this via an organisation.

Comment: You are just missing the username/password in your pod repo add command url. I provided workflow examples and a success workflow run so that you can see it working.

Comment: The first thing I would try is updating `actions/checkout` to `v2`. There have been many improvements since `v1`, and some of them were related to persisting credentials so that further steps could use git commands easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't provided the API token in the `pod repo add https://github...` command and most likely it fails due to that. Please add your personal API token to the github url like `<token>@github.com`. You can use `secrets` and `env` to do the same.

Most likely the following should help pass the error you are encountering:

```
name: Swift

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - enhancement/*
      - develop
      - develop/*
      - release
      - release/*

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        destination: ['platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.3,name=iPhone 11']
        xcode: ['/Applications/Xcode_11.6.app/Contents/Developer']
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.STRIVE_ACTIONS_SECRET }} # PAT
      - name: Bundle Update
        run: gem install bundler:1.17.2
      - name: Bundle Install
        run: bundle install

      - name: Specs Repo
        run: pod repo add Strive-Pod-Specs https://${POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN}@github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs.git
        env:
          POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN }}
      - name: Dependencies
        run: bundle exec pod install
        env:
          DEVELOPER_DIR: ${{ matrix.xcode }}
      - name: Build and test
        run: bundle exec fastlane scan --destination "${destination}" --scheme "CI"
        env:
          destination: ${{ matrix.destination }}
          DEVELOPER_DIR: ${{ matrix.xcode }}
```

The modified lines are:

```
            run: pod repo add Strive-Pod-Specs https://${POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN}@github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs.git
            env:
              POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN }}
```

Make sure you define a secret POD_GITHUB_API_TOKEN with your personal access token.

Comment: Hi @manishg i have this line in my podfile source "'https://github.com/{private podspec url}'". when trying to pod install.  after pod repo add, its keep failing with 
fatal: could not read Username for "https://github.com": Device not configured

Comment: Any update on this, getting the same results

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling that `git` needs you to authenticate or authorize. So there are multiple options for you to achieve that.

**The first and the most recommended option** is to use `SSH` instead of `HTTPS`. So the machine will use the key automatically and will not ask you for the username. and password every time. So the URL would be like: `ssh://<user>@github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs.git`

**The second option** is to hard code the username and password of the git. This is **NOT** recommended and it's very insecure. (But still an option) [Read this document for more description](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)
So the URL would be like `https://<user:pass>@github.com/KeteraUK/Strive-Pod-Specs.git`

**The other option** you have is to set a helper application that injects the password in the process. You may already have one configured, but `git` may simply not be able to find it. The above document page has information on this option as well. You can cache it globally by `git config --global credential.helper cache` or store it permanently by `git config credential.helper store`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add username and token to your pod repo add. Check the setup below with examples

[Sample workflow with success run](https://github.com/meroware/test-workflows/runs/1060502612)

[Sample workflow code](https://github.com/meroware/test-workflows/blob/master/.github/workflows/private-pod.yaml)

```
 name: Swift

 on:
   push:
 jobs:
   test:
     name: Test
     runs-on: macOS-latest
     strategy:
       matrix:
         destination: ['platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.3,name=iPhone 11']
         xcode: ['/Applications/Xcode_11.6.app/Contents/Developer']
     steps:
       - name: Checkout
         uses: actions/checkout@v1
         with:
           token: ${{ secrets.GITHUBTOKEN }}
       - name: Bundle Update
         run: gem install bundler:1.17.2
       - name: Bundle Install
         run: bundle install
       - name: Specs Repo
         run: pod repo add ColorMatchTabs https://meroware:${{ secrets.GITHUBTOKEN }}@github.com/meroware/ColorMatchTabs.git
```

NOTE: For this example I made ColorMatchTabs into a private repo so that I could setup a pipeline for this. Let me know if you have follow up questions but I think this should suffice your question very well

[Line that was edited that you care about](https://github.com/meroware/test-workflows/blob/ec6e2ccbdce946f70465e1bb0065af485d6b7cf3/.github/workflows/private-pod.yaml#L23)

```
    pod repo add ColorMatchTabs https://meroware:${{ secrets.GITHUBTOKEN }}@github.com/meroware/ColorMatchTabs.git
```

Also, you don't need to create env variables for all your secrets. You can just use them directly in the run. The only reason to add them to env is for actions or commands that grab them directly from envs.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me. Add in your workflow file.

```
  - name: Credentials
    run: |
       git config --global credential.helper store
       echo "https://UserName:token@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
```

for more [here](https://%5BResolve%5D-How%20to%20clone%20private%20spec%20repo%20in%20CocoaPods%20within%20GitHub%20Actions?)
The first step is named "run" and has the command git config --global credential.helper store. This command sets the Git configuration to store the credentials entered by the user in a plain-text file on the local file system. This command writes the credentials for the GitHub account to the ~/.git-credentials file. The echo command writes the string value of the GitHub account credentials to the file, and the > operator redirects the output of the echo command to the specified file path (~/.git-credentials in this case). The ~ symbol is a shorthand for the current user's home directory.

Overall, this code block sets up the Git configuration to store credentials and writes the GitHub account credentials to the ~/.git-credentials file.